# Find fixed field of K-automorphisms of $L:=\mathbb{R}(X,Y)$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

If $L:=\mathbb{R}(X,Y)$ and $G=\{\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2}\}$ where

$\sigma_{1}(X)=X\;\;,\;\;\;\sigma_{2}(X)=-X$

$\sigma_{1}(Y)=Y\;\;,\;\;\;\sigma_{2}(Y)=-Y$

Find $L^{G}$

So by def of $L^{G}:=\{l\in L\;\;\displaystyle\forall_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(l)=l\}$ i.e I need to find elements of $L$ that will be invariant under $K$-automorphism of L.

$\sigma_{i}(X^2)=\sigma_{i}(X)^2=(\pm X)^2=X^2\Rightarrow X^2\in L^{G}$

$\sigma_{i}(Y^2)=\sigma_{i}(Y)^2=(\pm Y)^2=Y^2\Rightarrow Y^2\in L^{G}\;,\;i=1,2$

Also

$\sigma_{1}(XY)=XY$ and

$\sigma_{2}(XY)=(-X)(-Y)=XY\Rightarrow XY\in L^{G}$

So If we let $K:=\mathbb{R}(X^2,Y^2,XY)$ then $K\subseteq L^{G}$

And to show other inclusion I will use the tower law. 
But my book says that $L^{G}=\mathbb{R}(X^2,XY)$

Why $Y^2$ is not taken in the smaller field?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\sigma_i(X^2)$ and $\sigma_i(Y^2)$ in the 7/8th line?

Comment: You can get $Y^2 = \frac{(XY)^2}{X^2}$. Therefore your fields are in fact the same.

Comment: @BISHD: Yes, it was a typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: @BISHD: Ah I forgot that this is a field of rational functions:) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about your calculations. But, the fields in fact agree, ie.
$$\Bbb R(X^2,XY,Y^2) = \Bbb R(X^2,XY)$$
This is because 
$$Y^2 = \frac{(XY)^2}{X^2}$$
and is therefore already included.